# Return a value after postgreSQL identify a sequency in a array

Tags: sql, postgresql

i need to find the correspond position in array B that starts a sequence in a array A of a query in postgreSQL.

My dataset look like

```
name         A             B
apple    | {0,0,1}  |  {x  y  z}
bean     | {0,0,0}  |  {i  h  j}
rice     | {0,1,0}  |  {o  l  ç}
```

and the sequence is 0,1

so i need that query return

```
Apple    |  y
bean     |
rice     |  o
```

How can I do?

I tried to use 'any()', but it just returns apple and rice rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this quite tricky, because I don't know a way to search for one array within another in Postgres -- and return the index.  So, this requires some unnesting.

Try this:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('apple', array[0,0,1], array['x', 'y', 'z']),
                   ('bean', array[0,0,0], array['i', 'h', 'j']),
                   ('rice', array[0,1,0] , array['o', 'l', 'ç'])
           ) v(name, a, b)),
     comparison as (
      select v.*
      from (values (array[0,1])) v(comp)
     )
select name,
       min(case when v_array = comp then e end)
from (select v.*, x.*,
             (array_agg(d) over (partition by v.name order by x.rn rows between current row and unbounded following))[1:array_length(c.comp, 1)] as v_array,
             c.comp
      from (values ('apple', array[0,0,1], array['x', 'y', 'z']),
                   ('bean', array[0,0,0], array['i', 'h', 'j']),
                   ('rice', array[0,1,0] , array['o', 'l', 'ç'])
           ) v(name, a, b) cross join
           unnest(a, b) with ordinality x(d, e, rn) cross join
           comparison c
     ) vx
group by name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=53da82362cff69f817ff74283bd24839) is a db<>fiddle.